# Scraping instagram photos link using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, instagram, scrape

I'm trying to scrape links of the photos for some hashtag. Instagram has never ending scrolling feed, so I want to scroll down five times and then scrape all links of the pictures I can see, but every time my bot scrape only 48 links.

```
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'+hashtag) 

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

x=1
while x<=5:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    #sleep(1)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:   
       break
    last_height = new_height
    x=x+1


elems =driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]

r = re.compile(".*/p/.")
links = list(filter(r.match, links))
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, `document.body.scrollHeight` is a constant for a given window, so you are always scrolling to that absolution location.  I think you want `scrollBy`.

Comment: `crollBy` works fine. Thanks Tim